# Child terminated with exit code 2 for running celeryd service in production

Tags: python-3.x, django

i am using celery version 5.1.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 with python 3.8 and Django 3.0 .In my production i am unable run the schedule tasks.

here is my /etc/systemd/celerd.conf

```
# Name of nodes to start
# here we have a single node
#CELERYD_NODES="w1"
CELERYD_NODES="worker1"
# or we could have three nodes:
#CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"

CELERY_APP="mcam"

# Absolute path to "manage.py"
# CELERY_BIN="/home/ravi/deploy/mcam/mcam/server/mcam/manage.py"
#CELERY_BIN="/home/ravi/.virtualenvs/lightdegree/bin/python manage.py celery"
CELERY_BIN="/home/ravi/.virtualenvs/lightdegree/bin/celery"
# How to call manage.py
CELERYD_MULTI="celery beat"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
# m3.medium instance has 1 vCPU. Hence the concurrency is limited to 2
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=4"

# %N will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%N.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%N.pid"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
```

this my /etc/systemd/system/celeryd.service

```
 [Unit]
Description=Celery Beat Service
After=network.target
Requires=gunicorn.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
#Type=forking

User=ravi
Group=ravi
EnvironmentFile=/etc/systemd/celeryd.conf
WorkingDirectory=/home/ravi/deploy/mcam/server/mcam
#ExecStart=/home/ravi/.virtualenvs/lightdegree/bin/python manage.py celery -l debug -A mcam beat

ExecStart=/home/ravi/.virtualenvs/lightdegree/bin/celery multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}
#ExecStop=/home/ravi/.virtualenvs/lightdegree/bin/celery ${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} \

 # --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}

ExecReload=/home/ravi/.virtualenvs/lightdegree/bin/celery ${CELERY_BIN} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}



[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

here are the commands what i used and error what i am getting

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

`sudo systemctl reset-failed celeryd.service`

`sudo systemctl restart celeryd`

`sudo systemctl status celeryd`

```
● celeryd.service - Celery Beat Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/celeryd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2022-03-31 06:36:48 BST; 8s ago
  Process: 17869 ExecStart=/home/ravi/.virtualenvs/lightdegree/bin/celery multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_
 Main PID: 17869 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 31 06:36:47 ip-xxx systemd[1]: Started Celery Beat Service.
Mar 31 06:36:48 ip-xxx celery[17869]: celery multi v5.1.2 (sun-harmonics)
Mar 31 06:36:48 ip-xxx celery[17869]: > Starting nodes...
Mar 31 06:36:48 ip-xxx celery[17869]:         > worker1@ip-xxx: OK
```

Here when i open my CELERYD_LOG_FILE there is no info

```
(lightdegree) ravi@ip-xxx:~$ cd /var/log/celery/
(lightdegree) ravi@ip-xxx:/var/log/celery$ ls
(lightdegree) ravi@ip-xxx:/var/log/celery$
```

Here is the data what is happening when i run my command sudo journalctl -u celeryd

```
-- Logs begin at Fri 2022-03-04 20:30:05 GMT, end at Thu 2022-03-31 06:57:02 BST. --
Mar 04 20:33:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:33:00,063: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Synchronizing schedule...
Mar 04 20:33:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:33:00,069: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Scheduler_Test_Task (eve
Mar 04 20:33:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:33:00,070: DEBUG/MainProcess] subscription.tasks.scheduler_test sent. id->dcc342d
Mar 04 20:33:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:33:00,071: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 3.00 minutes.
Mar 04 20:36:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:36:00,089: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Synchronizing schedule...
Mar 04 20:36:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:36:00,096: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Scheduler_Test_Task (eve
Mar 04 20:36:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:36:00,097: DEBUG/MainProcess] subscription.tasks.scheduler_test sent. id->0691a9a
Mar 04 20:36:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:36:00,101: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 3.00 minutes.
Mar 04 20:39:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:39:00,001: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Scheduler_Test_Task (eve
Mar 04 20:39:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:39:00,002: DEBUG/MainProcess] subscription.tasks.scheduler_test sent. id->d93ee48
Mar 04 20:39:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:39:00,006: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 59.99 seconds.
Mar 04 20:39:59 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:39:59,998: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Synchronizing schedule...
Mar 04 20:40:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:40:00,005: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task generate_qrcode_existing
Mar 04 20:40:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:40:00,006: DEBUG/MainProcess] crm.tasks.generate_qrcode_existing sent. id->9115ae
Mar 04 20:40:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:40:00,008: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 2.00 minutes.
Mar 04 20:42:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:42:00,011: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Scheduler_Test_Task (eve
Mar 04 20:42:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:42:00,011: DEBUG/MainProcess] subscription.tasks.scheduler_test sent. id->6e0b1d8
Mar 04 20:42:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:42:00,013: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 3.00 minutes.
Mar 04 20:44:59 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:44:59,998: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Synchronizing schedule...
Mar 04 20:45:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:45:00,004: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Remind_if_job_timer_not_
Mar 04 20:45:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:45:00,005: DEBUG/MainProcess] crm.tasks.notify_unstopped_jobs sent. id->8d2b8dec-
Mar 04 20:45:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:45:00,007: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Scheduler_Test_Task (eve
Mar 04 20:45:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:45:00,008: DEBUG/MainProcess] subscription.tasks.scheduler_test sent. id->684cf95
Mar 04 20:45:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:45:00,010: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Remind_if_job_timer_not_
Mar 04 20:45:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:45:00,010: DEBUG/MainProcess] crm.tasks.notify_unstarted_jobs sent. id->3cccac68-
Mar 04 20:45:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:45:00,011: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 3.00 minutes.
Mar 04 20:48:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:48:00,001: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Scheduler_Test_Task (eve
Mar 04 20:48:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:48:00,001: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Synchronizing schedule...
Mar 04 20:48:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:48:00,006: DEBUG/MainProcess] subscription.tasks.scheduler_test sent. id->5410a44
Mar 04 20:48:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:48:00,007: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 2.00 minutes.
Mar 04 20:50:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:50:00,000: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task generate_qrcode_existing
Mar 04 20:50:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:50:00,001: DEBUG/MainProcess] crm.tasks.generate_qrcode_existing sent. id->f78808
Mar 04 20:50:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:50:00,002: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 59.99 seconds.
Mar 04 20:51:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:51:00,035: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Synchronizing schedule...
Mar 04 20:51:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:51:00,041: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Scheduler_Test_Task (eve
Mar 04 20:51:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:51:00,042: DEBUG/MainProcess] subscription.tasks.scheduler_test sent. id->c8229c0
Mar 04 20:51:00 ip-xxx python[30931]: [2022-03-04 20:51:00,045: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 3.00 minutes.
lines 1-38
```

please help how i schedule tasks work fine in my production server

Comment: The output gives you a clue: `Invalid value for '-l' / '--loglevel'`. The problem is that you have not defined `CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL` in your configuration, so an empty value gets passed to the script. You need to define `CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL` in `celeryd.conf`.

Comment: Thank you for your help after adding CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL my logfile issue is solved but still its showing Active: inactive (dead) i have edited my error and code please help me

Comment: Check the logs for the service - `sudo journalctl -u celeryd`, there should be a clue there about what is still failing. If not, check the `CELERYD_LOG_FILE`.

Comment: when i run the command sudo journalctl -u celeryd i couldn't find any clue or issue andwhen i open my CELERYD_LOG_FILE there is no info .here i am editing the question and sharing the data pls have a look and help me